# Missing styles prevent preview of layout. How to resolve?

Tags: android-studio

I had a preview build installed which would render my layouts fine but when I tried to load some sample projects there would be some issue about not finding the sdk (even though it was pointing to the right location).  It's been a few months since I updated AS and so I installed the latest stable build.  I now can load sample projects without any sdk location problems, but now I always get errors when trying to preview a layout.

Specifically, it's saying there are missing styles, in this case `'?attr/actionBarPopupTheme` (image below).  This is a sample project (ListPopupMenu) and so it should be there somewhere, right?  How can I resolve this?

I'm using Build #AI-143.2489090

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change your app theme(click the button called “AppCompat”) to any other theme like AppTheme with no actionbar(just try four to five theme)

If that doesn't work,turn down the API version,the green robot button right side of theme button

If that is still not working,restart andoid studio

Comment: Can you show more details about your layout file? correction of your code can cause that problem too